# What's the correct way to install a grails plugin from a zip file?

Tags: grails, plugins

In recent versions of Grails [`install-plugin`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html) command has been deprecated. What is now the recommended way of installing a plugin that is not available via some repository. Assume the plugin is only available locally as zip file, e.g. after running `grails package-plugin`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is to place the zip file in the project's lib folder and then add an entry in the BuildConfig.groovy. For example:

```
1. 'grails-image-tools-1.0.5.zip' placed in lib.
2. runtime ":grails-image-tools:1.0.5" added to BuildConfig.groovy
```

Since the dependency manager looks inside the project's lib folder as well, I don't have to worry about setting any paths etc.

**EDIT:**
The latest Grails version that I worked on was 2.1.1. I'm unable to check but according to @Saurabh's comment below this isn't applicable for Grails 2.4.3

**EDIT2:** 
But @Jay says that it works with 2.4.5

Comment: I haven't worked in Grails for a while now. I'll mention the latest version that I tried this with. Thanks @Saurabh

Comment: I hope you're able to find a way to make it work, @samkitshah

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is ***the correct way*** but we get it working:

1. Download and unzip the plugin in a directory within your project
2. Change your `BuildConfig.groovy` file to point to the new plugin

Example: Download webflow.zip plugin and unzip it into a `plugins` directory within your project. Add this line at end of your `BuildConfig` file

```
grails.plugin.location."webflow" = "plugins/webflow"
```