# Grails 1.3.9 and grails-melody: javamelody.jar not packaged when building war with OpenJDK 1.6

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, java

We are maintaining a webapp developed in Grails 1.3.9.

For monitoring performance, the app had grails-melody 1.21 plugin installed.

It seems that the plugin is not available in the repositories any more for grails 1.3.x. I downloaded it from [google-code](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/downloads/list?can=2&q=grails) as suggested in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/Downloads?tm=2).

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751285/whats-the-correct-way-to-install-a-grails-plugin-from-a-zip-file) in stackoverflow suggests that zipped plugins can be put in lib and then referenced from BuildConfig.groovy.

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:1.3.9"
    build ":tomcat:1.3.9"
    compile ":dojo:1.6.1.17"

    // Downloaded from
    // https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/downloads/list?can=1&q=grails
    // Installed from lib
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751285/whats-the-correct-way-to-install-a-grails-plugin-from-a-zip-file

    compile ":grails-melody:1.21"
}
```

I did that and this procedure worked fine when building war file with Oracle JDK 7 (on Ubuntu 14.04). I had to rename grails-grails-melody-1.21.zip to grails-melody-1.21.zip so that it was found.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

During the build, melody's dependencies were loaded at the beginning of the build process, when grails file were copies as well:

```
...
Downloading: /home/matejk/devel/grails/grails-1.3.9/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: /home/matejk/devel/grails/grails-1.3.9/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: /home/matejk/devel/grails/grails-1.3.9/lib/groovy-all-1.7.8.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: /home/matejk/devel/grails/grails-1.3.9/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar ...
Download complete.
...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.jar.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.jar.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.jar.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: /home/matejk/devel/grails/grails-1.3.9/lib/aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar ...
...
```

Resulting war file had javamelody, jrobin and itext jars in WEB-INF/lib.

However, the requirement is to build the app with JDK 1.6 on another machine (Jenkins) where clean checkout of sources is done for every build.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Download of jars happened later in the build process:

```
Executing hibernate-1.3.9 plugin post-install script ...
Plugin hibernate-1.3.9 installed
Installing zip /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2/cache/org.grails.plugins/grails-melody/zips/grails-melody-1.21.0.zip... ...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/etermin-2.4/target/projects/etermin-2.4/plugins/grails-melody-1.21
    [unzip] Expanding: /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2/cache/org.grails.plugins/grails-melody/zips/grails-melody-1.21.0.zip into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/etermin-2.4/target/projects/etermin-2.4/plugins/grails-melody-1.21
Installed plugin grails-melody-1.21 to location /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/etermin-2.4/target/projects/etermin-2.4/plugins/grails-melody-1.21. ...
Resolving plugin JAR dependencies ...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bull/javamelody/javamelody-core/1.44.0/javamelody-core-1.44.0.jar.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.jar.sha1 ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.jar ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jrobin/jrobin/1.5.9/jrobin-1.5.9.jar.sha1 ...
Download complete.
```

However, when creating war with that JDK, javamelody, jrobin and itext jars are not packaged.

Consequently deployment and startup of webapp fails.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
```

- Is the procedure to install plugin from local directory correct?
- Any ideas how to resolve this problem to make jars to be packaged into war?

Thanks,

Matej

**EDIT:** After removing grails files in ~/.grails/1.3.9/ the behaviour with JDK 6 and JDK 7 is the same:

jar files are not packaged and deployment fails.

Comment: The procedure to install the plugin looks fine (and has the desired effect).

Comment: Have you tried running it with `run-app`? Does that yield the same results?

Comment: One more: If you extract the WAR (just unzip it) does it contain the JAR files in `WEB-INF/lib/`? It would be good to narrow down whether it is a build-step failure, a classpath issue, or something nice and weird...

Comment: Thanks for feedback. As I wrote above, WEB-INF/lib does not contains jars. run-app works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I managed to solve this issue was to explicitly include melody's deps to BuildConfig.groovy (copy from plugin's dependencies):

```
dependencies {
        // Deps for grails-melody (copied from plugin deps) that are *not* included automatically with plugin.

        compile "net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-core:1.44.0"
        compile ("com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7") {
            excludes "bcmail-jdk14", "bcprov-jdk14", "bctsp-jdk14"
        }
        compile "org.jrobin:jrobin:1.5.9"
    }
    plugins {
        compile ":grails-melody:1.21"
    }
```

I saw a few bugs open in Grails JIRA that might be related to what I was experiencing and was resolved in 2.x

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7608

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem for the integration of another plugin in with Grails 1.3.7

I know that what i'm saying is not a best practice, however i made this workaround.

Put the .zip of plugin in a folder that you want in your project, and commit into your svn repo.

After in your local enviorment you can use the grails installPlugin script specifying the plugin you want to install.

When you need to build app on other machine, you can put also a script in your project that a user can call. 
That script will contain first grails installPlugin and after, the grails war command.

Another way to do that is, if you have checked out all the souce code of the plugin for example in a folder called myPlugin (named my-plugin) and your project is in folder myProgect and each folder are in the same directory, you can add a line of code in your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.location.'my-plugin' = "../myPlugin"
```

Obviusuously if the plugin folder is not in the same path you can put right path:

```
grails.plugin.location.'my-plugin' = "../path/to/plugin/myPlugin"
```

This way don't need to call install plugin method, grails know that dependencies and package the plugin.

Hope i help you,
best regards.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it did not help. Plugin's deps were never included automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a local repository manager such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) and have the Grails plugins downloaded from this repository.
You can create a [local](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories) Artifactory repository for Grails plugins, not available in the Grails plugin repository, and deploy the 1.21 version of the JavaMelody Grails Plugin.
Next you need to add this local repository to the list of repositories Grails is resolving from (BuildConfig.Groovy):

```
groovy grails.project.dependency.resolution = { 
    ... 
    repositories { 
      grailsPlugins() 
      grailsHome() 
      mavenRepo "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/grails-plugins-local/"
      grailsCentral() 
   } 

   plugins { 
      build ":grails-melody:1.21" 
   }
   ...
}
```

Take a look at [Managing plugins with Grails 1.3](https://spring.io/blog/2010/05/18/managing-plugins-with-grails-1-3) in the spring.io blog for more detailed information about this kind of solution.