# GRAILS PLugins iNstallation manually

Tags: grails, plugins, installation

I want to how to install a grails plugin maunally from a zip file.

Can anyone please help me out in this ??

Comment: Same question (with good answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751285/whats-the-correct-way-to-install-a-grails-plugin-from-a-zip-file

Comment: Failed to read artifact descriptor for lib:uploadr:zip:LATEST m getting this message every time i'm trying.