# How to install custom Grails plugin from .zip?

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm having some trouble installing a plugin into my Grails application from a .zip.

I know it's possible to install the plugin without packaging it first (which is the approach we have been using during development), however this solution is not suitable for us to go to production with.

I have packaged the plugin as `grails-manual-exception-plugin-0.1.zip`

So in buildConfig.groovy I have `compile 'grails-manual-exception-plugin:0.1'`

But Grails is having issues resolving the plugin... Currently the .zip is sitting in the lib folder of my project folder, as reccommended here: [What's the correct way to install a grails plugin from a zip file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751285/whats-the-correct-way-to-install-a-grails-plugin-from-a-zip-file).

I am using Grails 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in 2.4. Install the plugin to your local maven cache (`grails maven-install`), but you have to do this on every machine.

Other options you have is publishing the plugin or getting something like Artifactory running.

Comment: Yep that seems to be the case @zoran119, I've been able to install it into a remote maven repository and share it with the rest of the team. Thanks for your help :)