# install websocket chat plugin not found

Tags: grails

i am using grails 2.1.1

i see this [page](https://grails.org/plugin/wschat)..it says `Grails version: 2.0 > *`.
so if iam using grails 2.1.1 must be install with no error..

but after i am trying to install it..
i get this error...

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\grails-2.1.1 -Dbase.dir=C:\Users\User\Documents\chatting "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\grails-2.1.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -javaagent:C:\grails-2.1.1\lib\com.springsource.springloaded\springloaded-core\jars\springloaded-core-1.0.6.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\grails-2.1.1\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-1.8.8.jar;C:\grails-2.1.1\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\grails-2.1.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf "run-app -plain-output"

|Loading Grails 2.1.1
Error |
WARNING: Specified dependency definition compile(wschat:1.24-SNAPSHOT3) is invalid! Skipping..
|Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User\Documents\chatting/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\cache-1.0.0/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\database-migration-1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/ivy-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/jars/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/bundles/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1.24/grails-wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User\Documents\chatting/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\cache-1.0.0/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\database-migration-1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/ivy-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/jars/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/bundles/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1.24/grails-wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User\Documents\chatting/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\cache-1.0.0/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\database-migration-1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\projects\chatting\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/ivy-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/jars/wschat-1.24.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/wschat/bundles/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/wschat-1.24.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1.24/grails-wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24!wschat.zip:

      C:\Users\User/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/wschat/1.24/wschat-1.24.zip

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#wschat;1.24: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:wschat:1.24



Process finished with exit code 1
```

why?

i already set log to 'warn' but still not installed..after this error..
i tried to install 1.12 and 1.13 version..but i get same error..

i tried this... `grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins"`

```
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: #wschat;1.24-SNAPSHOT2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'https://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1_24-SNAPSHOT2/wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'; 

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        https://grails.org/plugins: bad organisation found in https://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1_24-SNAPSHOT2/wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

|Downloading: wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom
|Downloading: wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: #wschat;1.24-SNAPSHOT2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'https://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1_24-SNAPSHOT2/wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'; 

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        https://grails.org/plugins: bad organisation found in https://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1_24-SNAPSHOT2/wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

|Downloading: wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom
|Downloading: wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: #wschat;1.24-SNAPSHOT2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'https://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1_24-SNAPSHOT2/wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'; 

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        https://grails.org/plugins: bad organisation found in https://grails.org/plugins/grails-wschat/tags/RELEASE_1_24-SNAPSHOT2/wschat-1.24-SNAPSHOT2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- :wschat:1.24-SNAPSHOT2



Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: its look like only run with grails 2.4 +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your repository

```
repositories {

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()



        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org/"
        mavenRepo "http://grails.org/plugins/"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins-releases/"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
```

}

Don't remove the other mavenRepo

If all else fails then download the zip file and follow the instructions here:
[What's the correct way to install a grails plugin from a zip file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751285/whats-the-correct-way-to-install-a-grails-plugin-from-a-zip-file)

Comment: That is wierd I was able to install it I'll include all of the mavenRepo in my project

Comment: if you are using 2.1 then you can just download the plugin and use grails install-plugin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751285/whats-the-correct-way-to-install-a-grails-plugin-from-a-zip-file

Answer (score 0):

I got something from https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin this might help you

Dependency (Grails 2.X) :

```
compile ":wschat:1.24-SNAPSHOT2"
```

codebase for grails 2.X

Dependency (Grails 3.X) :

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:wschat:3.0.3"
```

Seems its not able to download plugin hence define grailsRepo in BuildConfig.groovy

```
grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins"

repositories {
    inherits true

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins" 
}
```

If again errors comes pls comment. Thanks.

Comment: `Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- :wschat:1.24-SNAPSHOT2`

Answer (score 0):

I have written the plugin and in all honesty I have not gone back that far in Grails to see if it works. I will give it a try and see where I get with in on 2.1.1

I should point you to an issue found on 2.3.5 which will also impact anything below 2.3.5 :

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/issues/5

In regards to your BuildConfig (this was 2.3.5)

```
// plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.50"
```

This needs to change to:

```
// plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
```

It seems I need to update the version information on that plugin:

I have just attempted it and yes as per your comment you need to define its version to be 7.055 or above since its of when websocket support was added to tomcat.

I just tried it and got:

```
Installed plugin tomcat-7.0.55
| Error Plugin tomcat-7.0.55 requires version [2.3 > *] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet. Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails.
```

It would appear in order to use this plugin you will need grails 2.3+

Comment: `build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"` this is in my buildConfig.groovy....that mean i am using tomcat:2.1.1 ?

Comment: yes so you need to comment it out and add in build ":tomcat:7.0.55" but check my updated answer this won't work. Also add the grailsRepo as pointed out by Anshul further down